# Laravel 4-- Dynamic multi-domain routing breaks model binding & links

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an application stack in Laravel that we're going to go ahead and switch to a SaaS model. In order to do this, I just assumed I could wrap all my routes in a group with dynamic domain properties, fire a filter, and then observe the $route parameters to make this occur.

I should note that this is actually a Multi-Tenancy application but we've actually decided to separate the databases out for this one.

So here we go:

In my `routes.php` file, I've got the following:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{domain}.{tld}', 'before' => 'database.setup'), function()
{
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'backend', 'before' => 'auth'), function () {
        //all of my routes
    });
});
```

As you can see from the above, when any route is requested, it's going to the `database.setup` filter that I've got defined in `filters.php`:

```
Route::filter('database.setup', function($route, $request){
    $domain = $route->getParameter('domain').'.'.$route->getParameter('tld');

    $details = DB::table('my_table')->where('domain', '=', $domain)->first();
    if($details){

        Config::set('database.connections.account', [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'my_host',
            'database' => Encryption::decrypt($details->db_hash, 'my_salt'),
            'username' => 'my_username',
            'password' => 'my_password',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
        ]);


        //these are things I was doing to get the URL-permalink working.
        Config::set('app.url', 'http://' . $domain);
        Config::set('app.domain', $domain);
        Config::set('session.domain', '.' . $domain);

        //This actually works exactly as I've intended
        Config::set('database.connections.default', 'account');
        DB::setDefaultConnection('account');
    }
});
```

Now initially I thought this was working fine. The correct record was pulled from the table, and the database switched on the fly without issue while destroying the previous instance. *Great*.

However, I noticed that I've lost all of my model binding relationships in the routes.

A route such as this:

```
Route::get('/shipping/packages/{package}', 'PackageController@get');
```

With a model defined as such:

```
Route::model('package', 'Package');
```

Unfortunately always results in this:

```
No query results for model [Package].
```

Now, if I remove my filter from the Route, everything works fine, but the default database will be used *a big nono for my application*.

Lastly, all of the permalink structure seems to be completely broken. Instead of seeing my domain when I hover over a link, such as:

```
http://example.com/shipping/packages/package
```

I instead see:

```
%7Bdomain%7D.%7Btld%7D/shipping/packages/package
```

I have no idea why this is occurring.

I've tried overloading the response object, altering the settings for the site Configuration within the filter, and a host of other things, but I always end up having the same issue in some way or another.

I'd be greatly appreciative if anyone has any clue's on how to solve this issue.

Comment: can you try with `'domain' => '{domain}.{tld}.example.com'` and `$domain = $route->getParameter('domain').'.'.$route->getParameter('tld').'.example.com'` in your code

Comment: @ChetanAmeta Okay. I gave that a go. What resulted is that no account entry was found because the domain didn't match in the database, so it took me to the Saas Service's page as opposed to the client's page.

Comment: ok, only changing the app domain will work, `Config::set('app.domain', $domain.'.example.com');` leave `$domain = $route->getParameter('domain').'.'.$route->getParameter('tld');` as it was

Comment: @ChetanAmeta Unfortunately it didn't work. I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've figured out what the issue is.

I've apparently not read over the documentation well enough. If you walk through the router group call it will eventually invoke mergeGroup(), which in this particular function, you can observe the following code:

```
$new['where'] = array_merge(array_get($old, 'where', []), array_get($new, 'where', []));
```

Here, we can see that they're just using a stack to keep track of these values, so the literal interpretation of `{domain}.{tld}` was being pushed onto the stack.

This was working fine initially because my filter actually grabs them explicitly:

```
$domain = $route->getParameter('domain').'.'.$route->getParameter('tld');
```

To resolve this, I just needed to create my own helper function that would grab the $host (this is an extremely rudimentary implementation, but should help for clarity)

```
$domain = get_domain();

Route::group(array('domain' => $domain, 'before' => 'database.setup'), function()
```

Then in my helpers file, I've added the `get_domain()` function:

```
if ( ! function_exists('get_domain'))
{
    function get_domain()
    {
        $url_parts = parse_url(Request::root());

        return $url_parts['host'];
    }
}
```

Then I can simply call get_domain() in my filter as well and it'll always be in sync:

```
Route::filter('database.setup', function($route, $request){
$domain = get_domain();
```

This works perfectly now.